# How to remove folder name controller name and method name for url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have developed a project in Codeigniter 2x. In this project I use a folder in the controllers folder and crate my controller in this folder and declare a method in this controller. I send two parameters in this method.

My URL looks like this www.exmple.com/folder/home/index/$param1/$param2.

Where myfolder=folder name; home=controller name; index=Method name;
and $param1, $param2 is parameters name;

Now I am trying to remove my folder name,controller name and method name.

Comment: hi, why not use ci3? then you can do it with routes in **application/config/routes.php** you can add `$route['url-you-want/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'folder/controller/method/$1/$2';`

Comment: hi,@elddenmedio It an old and running project so I can not change it right now. And there is no problem without this issue.

Comment: https://codeigniter.com/userguide2/general/routing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can solve it by editing the Routes file. (application/config/routes.php):

```
$route['custom-url/(.*)/(.*)'] = 'folder/home/index/$1/$2';
```

Comment: hi I am following your instruction but Its showing  4o4 error.